# Load data from JSON or pure HTML?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am developing a site using CodeIgniter framework and hoping to integrate some AJAX call (using jQuery).

The website is about Horse Racing Tipping (Similar to footy tipping which user can submit a tipping by clicking a button). I like to avoid the need of user to reload the page when they submit their tipping (without AJAX they will have to reload the page over and over again).

Basically what I have in mind is: (feel free to correct me or give me better suggestion if you have in mind)

1. User submits their tipping (let's say for Race #1)
2. The form is submitted to the Server Side (PHP), it checks everything. If it's ok, it returns an "OK" flag.
3. If it receives "OK" flag, it requests the data for Race #1 from the Server
4. Server receives a request for Race #1 data
5. Using jQuery, it populates the Race #1 data into the browser.

**My question is:** Is it better to take JSON data and populate it into the browser using javascript? Or is it better to request the server-side (CodeIgniter in this case) to generate the particular HTML, and then fetch it using AJAX and populate it using javascript/jQuery (I.e: `$("div#r1").html(fetched_data)`)?

I know that the JSON data will be lightweight, but I will have to populate the data using JavaScript which can be easier or harder depending on the requirement.

What is your opinion regarding this issue?

Comment: JSON, because similar to MVC and CodeIgniter, you should separate logic from display. Clearly defining different parts for your JS, like the ajax request and how it is displayed, will make it easier to maintain and test. If you want a better idea of some of these conventions, look into JS libraries like Backbone, Underscore, etc. They promote an "MVC" JS style.

Comment: why make extra request in step 3? Can return data along with flag in step 2. Can also embed html in json....another option not suggested in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go with json, json is better.

Sending html in php is not a good choice. Return your data from php with `json_encode()`.

Edit :

For example, you have an array like this;

```
<?php
  $data = array(
    'races'=>array('race1'=>array('race','details','here'),'race2'),
    'horses' => array('horse1','horse2')
  );
?>
```

So you have to set html codes for each different data. But if you send this data with json, you can parse it from your view or included javascript and set every item in array as an object and use directly wherever you want.

Example for json;

```
//Ajax proccess here
success:function(response){
  if(response.races){
    $.each(response.races, function(i,item)){
      var $race = $('<div></div>');
      $race.addClass('race');
      $race.html('<h3>'+item.racename+'<h3>');
      $race.appendTo('#races');
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, you have full control with your json object. Accessing elements and creating new ones is always easier to handle. If you haven't use json object; you will always refresh all data with returned html. It's like writing all page from zero because of forgetting a ",".

Technical :
Php is server side, javascript is client side. So you can not have to do the all things in your server, it's would not a clever move.

Technical example :

```
<?php
$data = getDataFromDB();
if(count($data) > 0) //Proccess: 1
{
  $html = ''; //Proccess 2
  foreach($data as $race) //Process 3
  {
    $html .= '<div class="race"><h3>'.$race->name.'</h3></div>';
  }

  if($html != '') //Proccess 4
  {
    echo $html;
  }
}
?>
```

But if you use only json_encode it would be only one proccess...

That's why it's better to work with json object with ajax.

Comment: Can you give a little bit justification of your answer? I would like to know the reason why go with JSON.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question. The original poster is aware that there are two ways of doing things and clearly wants people's opinions on the issue. He didn't specifically say that the answer had to contain 'why' but it was strongly implied.

Comment: First, don't use html in php when it's not necessary. Second, handling json data is easier than pure html from php. I'm updating my answer with examples.

Comment: In your opinion in security point of view, is handling JSON safer than the other? I've heard of the use of CSRF, but i'm not sure how it works.

Comment: `Sending html in php is not a good choice`..  based on what? Works fine and is simpler to insert html than parsing json

Comment: Really? Works fine, yes. Simpler to insert html than parsing json, when you work with ajax NO. Because when you create html tags in php you have to send them, insert them and after all do things with javascript. If you want a answer that describes why?, i would tell you Time, Performance, Ease of use options. That's why.

Comment: @R. Canser Yanbakan: `Sending html in php is not a good choice` - not that I'm a fan of PHP, but even I wouldn't go that far! If all you need is to display the result of some asynchronous action, then HTML will be both faster and simpler; JSON is only really worthwhile if you need to perform some client side manipulation of the returned object(s). For example, in jQuery: $("div#widget").load("/widget") is about as simple as it gets. If you use fragment based templates you can even re-use the same template for your async calls - making it trivial to support non-JS capable clients. -1